# What data-structure is best suited for escape analysis?

Tags: compilers

I'm making a compiler using LLVM and LLVM's shadow-stack. I thought I might easy the load of the GC by using escape analysis and allocate some variables on the stack. Can I use my typed AST for this algorithm, or must I use a graph data-structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape analysis is a static analysis that determines whether the
lifetime of data exceeds its static scope. As such, it is not really
about stack vs heap allocation, just about lifetimes.

I don't think you can use your typed AST for escape analysis, because
what you are analyzing is the *data flow* of the program. The
appropriate structure for that is a graph, not a tree, because the
data flow is cyclic. So what you want is to build a *control flow graph*
(cfg), and perform data flow analysis on it.

Data flow analysis is a method or family of methods used for
implementing a whole range of compiler optimizations. Among them,
escape analysis. In it, you keep track of all objects, variables and
references of your program in a *points-to graph*. Each object and
variable is a node in the graph and, depending on how you implement
it, references between them can either be nodes or edges.

For example, consider this Java method:

```
public Pair myMethod(Pair[] pairs) {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    Pair p1 = new Pair(1, 2);
    Pair p2 = new Pair(3, 4);
    p1.value = f;
    pairs[0] = p1;
    return new Pair(5, 6);
}
```

Escape analysis would work roughly like this:

- **Line 1**: An array of type `Pair` is passed into the method and a
  `Pair` is returned from it. Add two nodes to the graph, one labelled
  `pairs` and another labelled `RETURN` both with flagged `foreigner`.
- **Line 2**: An object called `f` is created in the `myMethod`
  method- Add a node labelled `f` with flag `native` to the graph.
- **Line 3-4**: Add two more `native` nodes labelled `p1` and `p2`.
- **Line 5**: The field `value` of `p1` is set to refer to `f`. Add an
  edge from node `p1` to `f`.
- **Line 6**: First element of the `pairs` array is set to refer to
  `p1`. Add an edge from `pairs` to `p1`.
- **Line 7**: A new pair object is returned. Add an anonymous `native`
  node representing the pair object to the graph. Then add an edge
  from the `RETURN` node to this anonymous node.

After this step, traverse the graph beginning at the `foreigner` nodes
and flag all nodes visited as `foreigner`. It is exactly the same task
as the mark step in a mark and sweep garbage collector.

Then all objects that weren't reached by the traversal retain their
`native` flag and are eligible for stack allocation provided that the
compiler can statically determine their sizes. The rest must be
allocated on the heap.

I highly recommend watching the Youtube lectures of this professor:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVBQSR_HdL0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfAYWms9gUc

The
paper
[Escape analysis for Java](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320386)
also provides a fairly good description on how the algorithm works.